# Is there a way to read csv file from S3 using Java without downloading it

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was able to connect Java to AWS S3, and I was able to perform basic operations like listing buckets. I need a way to read a CSV file without downloading it. I am attaching my current code here.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {

        AWSCredentials credentials =new BasicAWSCredentials("----","----");

        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                .build();

        List<Bucket> buckets = s3client.listBuckets();
        for(Bucket bucket : buckets) {
            System.out.println(bucket.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. S3 is just a storage service - either you can upload, download or remove objects from S3 - but not sure if there is any way which I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean with "downloading"? You will need to download the file content to process it locally, but if you also mean "save it in a (temporary) file before processing", that shouldn't be necessary as long as whatever you're doing accepts an input stream (or a reader).

Answer (score 3):

There is a way with a code like this. In my code I am trying to get the file which we want to read in my S3Object obj , then I am passing that file to `InputStreamReader()`  :

```
S3Object Obj = s3client.getObject("<Bucket Name>", "File Name");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Obj.getObjectContent()));

// this will store characters of first row in array    
String row[] = line.split(","); 
                                   
// this will fetch number of columns
int length = row.length;

while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {

     // storing characters of corresponding line in an array
     String value[] = line.split(","); 
                                          
     for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
         System.out.print(value[i]+"   ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what and why your answer can fix the question ?

Comment: @Elikill58 just did that if you have any issues you can ask i will be happy to explain

Comment: That's clearly better ! I just fix the code indentation :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @jay and @Elikill58 is super helpful! This just adds a bit of clarity and accessibility to it.

To get an object from and S3 bucket after you have done all the [authentication work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MakingAuthenticatedRequests.html) is with the [.getObject(String bucketName, String fileName)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectStringString.html) function. Note what it says about file names in the documentation:

> An Amazon S3 bucket has no directory hierarchy such as you would find in a typical computer file system. You can, however, create a logical hierarchy by using object key names that imply a folder structure. For example, instead of naming an object sample.jpg, you can name it photos/2006/February/sample.jpg.
>
> To get an object from such a logical hierarchy, specify the full key
> name for the object in the GET operation. For a virtual hosted-style
> request example, if you have the object
> photos/2006/February/sample.jpg, specify the resource as
> /photos/2006/February/sample.jpg. For a path-style request example, if
> you have the object photos/2006/February/sample.jpg in the bucket
> named examplebucket, specify the resource as
> /examplebucket/photos/2006/February/sample.jpg.

Once you have an the S3Object that'll be returned, just pass it into this function below (which is just a modified version of @jay's that fixes a few errors)!

```
private static void parseCSVS3Object(S3Object data) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data.getObjectContent()));

    try {
        // Get all the csv headers
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] headers = line.split(",");

        // Get number of columns and print headers
        int length = headers.length;
        for (String header : headers) {
            System.out.print(header + "   ");
        }

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println();

            // get and print the next line (row)
            String[] row = line.split(",");
            for (String value : row) {
                System.out.print(value + "   ");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code to read the file, it needs the contents -- and that means copying it to the local system.

However, you can use ["range"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#ExampleGetRangeRequestHeaders) ([Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#setRange-long-)) to read just a part.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java NIO `Path`s and `Channel`s which are available in Java 1.8 and later then you can use the `aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3` package. With that package on your classpath Java calls to open a `Channel` or `Path` for an s3 URI will be delegated to the package allowing the application to access these files directly without needing to stage the file locally.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer it, but I think it may help future seekers.

We can take the help of AWS SDK. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-select.html) is an example on aws docs. See the Java section.

If anyone follows the doc, a file will be downloaded as **FileOutputStream** is used there to save the file. But you can store the output of your query in String as well like this:

```
String string = IOUtils.toString(resultInputStream);
```

If you follow the blog, you already know, **resultInputStream** is the output of your query.